# How to get String value in iphone

Tags: iphone

I have a class A and a Class B 
Class A has a method and NSString as return type 
 as shown below
Class A:

```
NSString *hello; 
hello =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[self method:stringname]];
-(NSString*)method:stringname {

return String123; 
}
```

Now in Class B :

```
NSString *hello1; 
hello1 =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:objA.hello];
NSLog("hello1 %@",hello1);
```

here i get the value as null the value is printed in Class A but not in Class B
rest everything @proprty and @synthesize is added

can any one tell me what is the correct ans for the above code

Comment: What is `String123` referring to ? Where and how is it initialized ?

Comment: its a String123 is a result of some calculation that is passed as return type

Comment: What is `objA`? Is is initialized at all ? If it is a member of Class B, did you initialize it ?

Comment: objA is object of class A and i have initialied it

Comment: Could you please post what exactly you are doing instead of posting as comments ? I mean the code, with a simple case of what you are doing.

Answer (score 0):

you can try this :

in class A

```
NSString *hello; 
hello =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[self method:stringname]];

+ (NSString*)method:stringname 
{
    return String123; 
}
```

Now in Class B :

```
NSString *hello1; 
hello1 =[[NSString alloc]initWithString:[ClassA method:string]];
NSLog("hello1 %@",hello1);
```